# Allow Authenticated User (non-group member) to Assign Task/Event/Form to a Group

Tags: commerce, entities, organic-groups

I'm trying to figure out how to accomplish this:

- Allow any authenticated user to submit a form to Groups A through Z.
- Members of Group A can view forms submitted only to Group A, and respond by updating the form with a file.
- It has to be secure, so filtering by the PHP url won't work.

I'm flexible with how this happens. Right now, using the CRM as a backend, I have an EntityForm that can be assigned to a CRM object, but I cannot figure out how to link a user to a CRM object to filter the EntityForm submission.

I've also contemplated hacking together some type of multi-merchant marketplace where tasks are submitted in the form of "orders" and each "merchant" can fulfill their orders that way, but I feel that has to be overkill for what I'm trying to do.